# Encoding detecting php

Tags: php, encoding

I have fallowing string: Ëè÷íûå âñòðå÷è
How to encode this string int UTF-8 file PHP?

I spend all day to get how to do this.

Comment: Make sure your file editor is set to store files in UTF-8 and you can just copy-paste this string to the file.

Comment: Like @Ondřej Mirtes said, make sure your file editor is set to store files in UTF-8, and you can check that that string is in UTF-8 with echo mb_detect_encoding('Ëè÷íûå âñòðå÷è');. So why re-encode it to UTF-8 ? ps: there's utf8_encode() to encode a non-UTF-8 to UTF-8 !

Comment: This question is unanswerable as is. I'd recommend you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) to get a basis for what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

However, I seem to remember it is quite difficult to detect encoding. On the other hand it is eay to convert if you know the source encoding:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php